# Cut out a custom shape from an image in P5.js

Tags: shapes, p5.js

I am trying to create jigsaw puzzle shapes using P5.js. After creating puzzle shapes, I want to cut areas from main image into pieces. For that I have options of using [GET()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get) or [COPY()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/copy):

But both of them take fix height and width as parameter. How can I copy a custom area like given in following shapes:

https://editor.p5js.org/techty/sketches/h7qwatZRb

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cutout = createGraphics(w, h);
cutout.background(255, 255);
cutout.blendMode(REMOVE);
//draw shape on cutout
let newshapeimagegraphic = createGraphics(w, h);
newshapeimagegraphic.image(myImg, 0, 0);
newshapeimagegraphic.blendMode(REMOVE);
newshapeimagegraphic.image(cutout, 0, 0);
image(newshapeimagegraphic, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).